# How to process CollectionView On SelectedItem event in ViewModel Code instead of Back-end Code of Content Page? Xamarin.Form

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, content-pages

I want to get data from the SelectedItem in CollectionView, but doing that I must work with SelectionChanged_EventHandler(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) which appear to be inside the Back-end code of the Content Page. I want to process this work inside my ViewModel code instead as I have to pass the data from SelectedItem to my ObservableCollection<> in the ViewModel code.

Is there any method that I can get data from the SelectedItem in CollectionView and also handle this event inside my ViewModel code?

Comment: use the `SelectionChangedCommand`

Comment: @Jason i tried it before. It works fine, but i could not figure out how do i access the selected item data. I only know how to use it as command which execute functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! There are several ways to do this:

**1) Using SelectedItem Bindeable property to trigger the event**

XAML:

```
<CollectionView
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ..../>
```

ViewModel:

```
public Item SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _selectedItem)
                    return;

                _selectedItem = value;
                TriggerMethodThatYouWant();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackgroundTest));
            }
        }
```

**2) Using a TapGestureRecognizer: this will trigger On Tapping, is different that selection but achieves the same**

Xaml:

```
<CollectionView
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding tapCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                      </DataTemplate>
                 </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
<CollectionView>
```

Viewmodel: You will have to create the command and the method

```
    public Command<Item> tapCommand { get; }
```

Comment: Hello Sir, i was wondering if you could help me another problem. I have a CollectionView>Grid with 2 Frame and 1 ScrollView inside. the inside of ScrollView has 1 Frame 1 Label, but the problem is my ScrollView can't be scrolled most of time. it does not scroll properly. here is the root CollectionView>Grid>ScrollView>Frame>Label. Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: The CollectionView is a scrolleable view, and inside you are using another Scrolleable view. I think that is the problem

Comment: Could you advise me what should i do? because i want to have a small Display with fixed height inside the CollectionView to display additional data which i can scroll .

Comment: Maybe you can keep the main UI simple, and then add behavior when clicked. To display a popup with more information, or another page

Comment: not working with maui in iOS